# Removing Design Tokens Dependency in Package

Tags: lightning-aura-components, unmanaged-package, package-dependency, design-tokens

I have a managed package that leverages design tokens in lightning components (and automatically pulls in our defaultTokens.tokens design token bundle as a dependency).

I am trying to create an unmanaged package for a demo, but am running into an issue being able to remove the defaultTokens.tokens design tokens bundle as a dependency to the lightning components. I'm not sure if it becomes an implicit dependency to every component by existing. I tried removing all CSS from the components, as well as removing all of the markup inside the design bundle without luck. Any ideas?

The rationale for this is that I <s>don't want to</s> can't delete the defaultTokens.token design tokens bundle in the target org (not mine), but the unmanaged package install won't allow me to bypass that file already existing in the target.

**EDIT:** I'm now wondering if this would preclude anyone from installing an unmanaged package of lightning components into an org that is using default tokens.